# Is the set of real numbers in $[0,1]$ with digits $1$ and $3$ only in their development in base $5$, dense in $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-numbers, decimal-expansion

> Let $E$ denote the set of real numbers in $[0,1]$ with digits $1$ and $3$ only in their development in base $5$. How to prove that $E$ is dense in $[0,1]$?

Is this the right way to see that E is dense?: $\forall x\in [0,1],\forall \epsilon\gt0,\exists n_0\in \mathbb N \mid d(x,e_n)\lt\epsilon,\forall n \ge n_0$ and $(e_n)_n\subset E$.

If so, how to find such a sequence $(e_n)_n$?

Comment: What do you mean that the single digits of their development? Are you saying $x$ of the form $0.13113131333113_5$?

Comment: @Soke yes, exactly

Comment: For the first question , the answer is yes . for the second question I think that the answer is that $E$ is not dense in $[0,1]$ and in order to find a counter example take some $x=\frac{3}{5}-\epsilon$,

Answer (score 1):

The set is clearly *not* dense in $[0,1]$: for example, $0$ is neither a limit point nor a point of $E$.

You may be wanting to prove that $E$ is *nowhere-dense* in $[0,1]$. That is, we say a set $E$ is nowhere-dense if its closure has an empty interior.